# RcppArmadillo with cxxfunction - how to load header file with function definition?

Tags: rcpp

I am using RcppArmadillo via cxxfunction. I would like to load functions defined as C++ header files. This works with cxxfunction alone, but not when RcppArmadillo is added into the mix. A minimal working example is given below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//My header file

#ifndef GUARD_myFunc
#define GUARD_myFunc

#include <Rcpp.h>

NumericMatrix myFunc(NumericMatrix Xin) {

    NumericMatrix Xout=Xin;

    return Xout;

}

#endif
```

-

```
##### My R script

rm(list=ls())

require("inline")
require("Rcpp")
require("RcppArmadillo")

X<-matrix(rnorm(9),3,3)

###works with RcppArmadillo
src1<-'Rcpp::NumericMatrix XR(XS);
arma::mat X(XR.begin(), XR.nrow(), XR.ncol(), false);
return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("X")=X);
'
Cfunc1<-cxxfunction(sig=signature(XS="numeric"), body=src1, plugin="RcppArmadillo")
print(X)
print(Cfunc1(X))

###works with myFunc.h
settings <- getPlugin("Rcpp")
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS <- paste("-I", getwd(), sep="")
src2<-'Rcpp::NumericMatrix XR(XS);
Rcpp::NumericMatrix XU=myFunc(XR);
return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("X")=XU);
'
Cfunc2<-cxxfunction(sig=signature(XS="numeric"), body=src2, includes=c('#include "myFunc.h"'),settings=settings)
print(X)
print(Cfunc2(X))

###Does not work with RcppArmadillo and myFunc.h
src3<-'Rcpp::NumericMatrix XR(XS);
Rcpp::NumericMatrix XU=myFunc(XR);
arma::mat X(XU.begin(), XU.nrow(), XU.ncol(), false);
return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("X")=X);
'
Cfunc3<-cxxfunction(sig=signature(XS="numeric"), body=src3, plugin="RcppArmadillo", includes=c('#include "myFunc.h"'),settings=settings)
print(X)
print(Cfunc3(X))
```

Comment: Unless you have specific reasons to stick with inline and its `cxxfunction()`, I wouldI recommend that you a) organize your code as a package and b) use Rcpp Attributes.   There are arguments for extra header files you could use -- but in longer term a package is probably what you want.

Comment: Hi Dirk. Thanks very much for your comments! OK, I'll proceed as you suggest then